# Equal Height Step Buttons in Smart Wizard

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, smart-wizard

The jQuery Smart Wizard https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard plugin has been around for several years and it appears development stopped about 3 years ago.  However, Smart Wizard still works quite well and I haven't found anything that is newer.

Since there is no active development, the author has not addressed how to make Smart Wizard work with responsive websites.  I've been able to remove most of the obstacles by setting widths to 100% and use Bootstrap columns in the wizard step panels.

Where I have hit a stumbling point is the large step buttons that display at the top of the wizard, especially in regard to making sure the buttons are all the same height when viewed on a mobile device.  I haven't used flexbox yet and don't know if that would work for this.  Has anyone else solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved at least in initial testing.  Added a handful of media queries to deal with the buttons.  I chose to only show two buttons across on small screens and 5 across on desktop.  Also, adjusted some heights and padding based on break points.